# ¿Cómo le asigno un valor a una variable en un formulario que llamo de otro formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo 2 formularios: padre e hijo ,  Dentro del formulario padre:

```
string stJugador = txtNomyAp.Text.ToUpper();
frmHjo nombre = new frmHijo();
nombre.guardarNombre(stJugador);
```

El método `guardarNombre(stJugador);` es un método del formulario hijo:

```
public void guardarNombre(string nombre)
{
    stNombreJugador = nombre;
}
```

Como verán, cuando el formulario padre le manda al hijo el nombre del jugador (`nombre.guardarNombre(stJugador);`), dentro del hijo este se asigna a `stNombreJugador` (que defini globalmente), pero cuando termina el método, el valor de `stNombreJugador` se pierde ya que se destruye la variable.

De que manera puedo hacer que se guarde permanente el valor de `stNombreJugador` ?

Comment: stNombreJugador es global? Global definida donde? No deberia tener el fomulario hijo su propia variable nombre?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi a la variable `stNombreJugador` la definí global en el form hijo

Comment: si esta definida en el formulario hijo, no esta global, esta dentro del scope de ese formulario.. entonces, donde estas tratando de recuperarla???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y si en lugar de guardar la informacion en variables, mejor creas una clase "Jugador" con su propiedad "Nombre" para que ahi puedas guardar el valor que quieres.